# Fixed Result Value

Tags: r

I'm making a simple lotto game, but the result is not fixed. Even if I use the set.seed() function, it can't be fixed, how can I fix it?

````
lotto<-function(game){
z<-matrix(NA, nrow = game, ncol = 6) 
colnames(z) <- c('N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4', 'N5', 'N6')
for(x in 1:game) {
  y <- sample(1:45, 6, replace = FALSE)
  print(sort(y))
  z[x,] <- sort(y)
}
write.csv(z, 'lotto.csv', row.names = FALSE, fileEncoding = 'UTF-8')
}

lotto(1)
lotto(5)
```
````

Comment: `set.seed` works fine for me, you probably used id wrong.

Comment: What do you mean you used the wrong ID?

Comment: typo, used *it wrong. You should show in your question how you used it.

Comment: After fixing the lotto value (1), you want to see if it matches the lotto value (5). However, since the value of the lotto 1 is not fixed, it cannot be moved to the next step. Is it impossible to randomly return only the lotto value (5) while the lotto value (1) is fixed?If set.seed() is used, both of them are fixed and cannot be solved.

Comment: Do you want `set.seed(1); lotto(1); set.seed(NULL); lotto(5)`?  `NULL` re-initializes the seed.

Answer (score 0):

by using `set.seed()` every thing is ok see :

```r
set.seed(42)
lotto(1)
#> [1]  1 10 18 25 36 37
lotto(5)
#> [1]  7 20 24 25 36 37
#> [1]  3 25 26 27 36 41
#> [1]  5 20 28 31 34 37
#> [1]  3 24 30 33 40 42
#> [1]  4  8 15 22 36 43
set.seed(42)
lotto(1)
#> [1]  1 10 18 25 36 37
lotto(5)
#> [1]  7 20 24 25 36 37
#> [1]  3 25 26 27 36 41
#> [1]  5 20 28 31 34 37
#> [1]  3 24 30 33 40 42
#> [1]  4  8 15 22 36 43
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: After fixing the lotto value (1), you want to see if it matches the lotto value (5). However, since the value of the lotto 1 is not fixed, it cannot be moved to the next step. Is it impossible to randomly return only the lotto value (5) while the lotto value (1) is fixed?If set.seed() is used, both of them are fixed and cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would help :

```r
lotto <- function(game) {
  z <- matrix(NA, nrow = game, ncol = 6)
  colnames(z) <- c("N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5", "N6")
  if (game == 1) {
    y <- sample(1:45, 6, replace = FALSE)
    print(sort(y))
    z[1,] <- sort(y)
  } else{
    set.seed(NULL)
    for (x in 1:game) {
      y <- sample(1:45, 6, replace = FALSE)
      print(sort(y))
      z[x,] <- sort(y)
    }
  }
  write.csv(z,
            "lotto.csv",
            row.names = FALSE,
            fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
}
set.seed(42)
lotto(1)
#> [1]  1 10 18 25 36 37
lotto(5)
#> [1]  6 13 20 23 27 33
#> [1]  7 11 13 19 24 42
#> [1] 10 15 35 38 40 41
#> [1] 15 21 30 31 35 45
#> [1] 15 19 25 35 36 42
set.seed(42)
lotto(1)
#> [1]  1 10 18 25 36 37
lotto(5)
#> [1]  7 11 16 24 27 41
#> [1]  5 10 20 22 25 35
#> [1] 12 13 17 25 27 42
#> [1] 10 25 29 37 39 41
#> [1] 11 20 23 24 26 28
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. You are like a god to me .... :)

Comment: nothing at all , We all worship the God.